# locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid for empty local name

Tags: c++, windows, g++, locale, msys2

I was writing a function for printing `u8string` to `ostream`. This is what I came up with:

```cpp
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::u8string_view str) -> std::ostream& {
    std::locale::global(std::locale{".utf8"});
    auto& ret = out << std::string_view{std::bit_cast<const char*>(str.data()), str.size()};
    std::locale::global(std::locale{""});
    return ret;
}
```

This compiles fine. But while executing, this fails saying:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

First I thought `".utf8"` locale might not be supported on my system (that's true). But even after I comment out that line, I'm still getting the same error. So the error must have been caused by using `""`.

I always thought an empty locale name sets the locale to the user's preference. If this is not happening, how should I restore the user-preferred locale after writing to the `ostream`?

I am using *g++ 12.2.0 Rev6, built by MSYS2 project* on *Windows 11 x64*.

Answer (score 0):

`std::locale::global` returns the previous locale, so you can use that to restore it:

```
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::u8string_view str) -> std::ostream& {
    auto locale = std::locale::global(std::locale{".utf8"});
    auto& ret = out << std::string_view{std::bit_cast<const char*>(str.data()), str.size()};
    std::locale::global(locale);
    return ret;
}
```

But why are you messing with the locale in the first place? Writing chars to an `ostream` is not affected by the locale. And when you actually do something with the stream that is affected by locale, you should change the stream's locale, not the global locale:

```
my_stream.imbue(std::locale{"en_US.utf8"})
```

PS: that is not a sensible use of `bit_cast`, you should use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @Chronical then probably I don't know how locale work in C++. I thought streams interpret the data is in `global` encoding and convert it to `imbue` encoding while writing. So, since the data I'm feeding is in `utf8` and I want to display it in user preferred locale, I changed `global` and didn't touch `imbue`.

Comment: If my terminal is using `ebcdic` and I have `ascii` strings in my application, what is the correct procedure to display them? Displaying them directly would produce gibberish afaik. How I thought is, you set `global` to `ascii` and `imbue` to `ebcdic` and I thought this will make stream to interpret data as `ascii` and convert it to `ebcdic` before printing.

Comment: @Chronical Please checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75266278/12357035) question.

Comment: @Chronical when to use `std::bit_cast` and when to use `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: You sue bit_cast when you want to reinterpret the bits of a value – i.e., interpreting a `double` as `int`. When you change the type of a pointer, you never want bit_cast.