# How to correctly display strings in user preferred locale in C++?

Tags: c++, string, locale, iostream

I posted this code in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263679/):

> ```
> auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::u8string_view str) -> std::ostream& {
>     std::locale::global(std::locale{".utf8"});
>     auto& ret = out << std::string_view{std::bit_cast<const char*>(str.data()), str.size()};
>     std::locale::global(std::locale{""});
>     return ret;
> }
> ```

I intended to convert `u8string` to a user-preferred locale before printing. But in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75264625/12357035) to that post, @Chronial pointed out that I was using the `global` locale wrongly.

I thought outstreams interpret the data in the `global` encoding and convert it to the `imbue`'d encoding while writing. So, since the data I'm feeding is in `utf8` and I want to display it in a user-preferred locale, I changed `global` and didn't touch `imbue` in the above code.

For Eg: If my terminal is using *EBCDIC* and I have *ASCII* strings in my application, what is the correct procedure to display them properly? Displaying them directly would produce gibberish, AFAIK.

What I thought is, if I set `global` to *ASCII* and `imbue` to *EBCDIC*, this will make the stream interpret data as *ASCII* and convert it to *EBCDIC* before printing.

The above scenario of converting from *ASCII* to *EBCDIC* is just taken as an example. I was seeking for a generic solution, not just for the case of *ASCII* to *EBCDIC*.

Comment: I am bad in C++ locales, but in C, `If my terminal is using ebcdic and I have ascii strings` I would set locale to ASCII, convert string to wide characters, set locale to EBCDIC, and then just printf("%Ls" the wide string. I.e. wide characters is the bridge between all locales, and setting locale sets the conversion method from strings to/from wide characters.

Comment: If it is possible, you can use [__a2e_s](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-a2e-s-convert-string-from-ascii-ebcdic). In my opinion, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @IvanVenkov Sorry, but I was seeking for a more generic solution, not just `__a2e_s()`. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard library is not really designed to help you in this scenario. You either have to handle the re-encoding yourself or use wide character streams. You will then have do decode your strings into wide character strings, write these to the stream and the stream will then use the locale/encoding it is imbued with to reencode the string.

But kind of app are you writing exactly that this actually matters to you? For most applications it should be fine to just write UTF8, since that is what all modern terminals should be configured to.

Comment: Setting `imbue` makes the stream convert the string to that encoding right? So, in this case, in which encoding it assumes the string to be in? Or, does it not re-encode the string at all?

Comment: I don't want to convert anything to non UTF-8. But I am really not understanding what are `global` and `imbue` locales meant to do. I thought `global` was string encoding of memory and `imbue` was string encoding of terminal.